# how to provide information from a mysql database on a website using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with providing infromation from a mysql database through php. I am working with brackets and always when I try to connect with my database (opening my connection, giving information about my server, port and the name of the dtabase -> shown in the code below) nothing happens. I can not administrate my database with phpmyadmin I know that would be easy. I also have xamp and a apache server working, but then I would have to use phpmyadmin to connect.

But is there a way to connect the database (created with mysql workbench running on localhost 127.0.0.1 and port 3306) only like that with my php file. Or is the problem that I have a mistake in my code?

Code:

File one: db_connection.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <header>

        <center> <h1>My New Website </h1> </center>

    </header>

    <body>

    <?php
        //die echo Funktion, ist dafür da, dass etwas in den Browser ausgegeben wird (same as Syso)
        //echo "Hello World!";

        function OpenConnection()
        {
            $dbhost = "localhost";
            $dbuser = "root";
            $dbpassword = "";
            $dbname = "dml_final";

            $connection = new mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname)
            or die ("Connection failed: %s\n". $connection -> error);

            return connection;
        }

        function CloseConnection()
        {
            $connection -> close();
        }

    ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

File two: index.php

```
<?php requires 'db_connection.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <header>

        <center> <h1>My New Website </h1> </center>

    </header>

    <body>

    <?php

    $connection = openConnection();

    echo "Connection successfully!";

    CloseConnection($connection);

    ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI, your db_connection.php should not contain all that HTML code to begin with. By requiring this in the other script, you will have all those HTML elements twice inside the final output of the second script, and that of course makes zero sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your current way, change `function` to `public function` so that it is globally available across your website, I recommend the following method instead:

```
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "root";
 $dbpassword = "";
 $dbname = "dml_final";

 $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);

 if(!$connection) {
  die("Connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error());
 }
```

And you include this in all of your PHP files. To close the connection, simply run a `mysqli_close($connection);`. I don't know about you, but I find this way more simple.